# Winter Bash 2020 "Log Out" not aligned with the username

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash-2020

On the top right-hand side of the [Winter Bash 2020 site](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/), you'll see your avatar and username (assuming you're logged in) and the "log out" link. It looks like they're supposed to be aligned, but it seems the "Log out" text is a couple of pixels lower than the username.

I took a screenshot and added some clarifying lines (click on it to get the full size picture that makes these lines a bit clearer):

[image]

You can see the top black line just hits the top of the capital "M" in my username, but there's a space between it and the top of the capital "L" in "Log out".
Similarly, the bottom line just touches the bottom of the "M", but clearly crosses the bottom of the "L".

It's not horrible, but once seen, it cannot be unseen.

**EDIT:**
Environment details for reproduction:

- Windows 10 Enterprise, 1909
- Resolution: 3840 * 2160
- Browers it reproduced in:

  - Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)
  - Firefox 83.0
  - Firefox 84.0.1
  - Microsoft Edge Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I wonder what the downvote on this question means. Is it a claim the bug can't be reproduced? That the bug report is not good enough? Or that this isn't a bug?

Comment: some others seem to downvote everything which is even slightly related to Winterbash

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard Hardly my first rodeo :) Not taking it too hard, just wondering

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard let's wait and see what happens on Monday :-)